# Firefox Extension - Is this allowed/legal?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I recently installed a Firefox extension and noticed that it was doing something very odd in the background.

I'm a web developer and use Wordpress mainly. One day I was working on a page in WP admin and switched to the Text rather than Visual mode so I could edit some HTML. I noticed a load of junk html in there hidden using display:none

The class names rang a bell, it was the name of the extension I had installed several weeks previous

I immediately uninstalled the extension but of course it was too late. Since it was injecting code right into the text entry boxes in Wordpress, all that junk got saved with my pages. I had to weed through dozens and manually delete this junk, which in some cases had affected the layout.

I contacted the developers, and they gave me some rubbish about it being totally normal, everyone does this sort of thing, its within the Mozilla dev terms, and that it was a feature not a horrific Malware as I was putting forward.

In this case it was just html/css, but what if they were injecting JS/php etc, they could be causing all kinds of damage

I just wondered from a development perspective what peoples thoughts were. Is this legal?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: did you agree to it in the terms and conditions displayed when you installed the plugin? Then it's legal

Comment: I'll have another read through, but it is still surprising that an extension can make permanent changes to websites in the background. This is not a web dev extension or anything that requires touching html code. Its just something they do in the background I imagine usually without ever being detected

Comment: legal != right of course. It sounds like a very evil plugin and I'm sure letting the extension hosting people know would help.

Comment: If they were injecting js/php it wouldnt have been approved by the addon approval process. This is a feature of the addon you are using probably.

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action is to spread awareness. I would not do here, but maybe write a detailed article explaining which extension it is, what it does, how, why it's bad, how to get rid of it, and alternatives.

Medium, your own blog, Hacker News and other social outlets will certainly be welcoming of such informations. The developers are very well aware of what they are doing so don't expect them to broadcast it and/or take action.

Be also sure to read their ToS again, see what you agreed to. If something seems suspicious you can talk to a lawyer or probably report them, altough this is beyond what I know.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Mozilla Addon reviewer. Please report your findings as Abuse report and/or addon review (it will be read).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cant find how to send a PM though

Comment: Sorry .. my mistake. There doesn't seem to be a PM facility here :(